# Game of Thrones / A Song of Ice and Fire tag clean up

Tags: discussion

I am seeing a lot of questions tagged with both [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) and [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire).

My understanding is that [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) is for the TV show and [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) is for the books.

Should we clean up tags that are clearly only related to one or the other based on:

1. the reference of the question or
2. where the OP wants answers sourced from?

Comment: Related (not dupe): [How should Game of Thrones questions tied to the TV show be tagged?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1690/21267)

Comment: How many questions are there currently which have both tags despite being only relevant to one of the book and the TV show?

Comment: @rand Probably very few; since most questions are applicable to both canons.

Comment: @Mooz In that case, this would seem to be a bit of a non-issue?

Comment: @Rand Perhaps, although I haven't researched the real numbers, so it could actually be an issue. I know that whenever I run into any case where both are tagged unnecessarily, then I correct the tags; I just haven't had to do it very often.

Comment: @Skooba You're right; they *are* quite different (at least will be from this point onward). However most of the issues brought up can apply to both canon at this point.

Comment: i saw a few where a question had called out a specific episode or chapter which prompted me to ask the question as the canon can be vastly different.